# How to get the current RuleContext class when visiting a TerminalNode?

Tags: antlr4

If I have

```
        @Override public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {
              node.getRuleContext(); // doesn't build
         }
```

How do I get the current RuleContext class?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
node.getParent().getPayload();
```

*This method returns whatever object represents the data at this note. For example, for parse trees, the payload can be a Token representing a leaf node or a RuleContext object representing a rule invocation. For abstract syntax trees (ASTs), this is a Token object.*